# Orion Context Broker Post ":" character

Tags: post, fiware, fiware-orion

When I make a POST call to the Orion Context Broker and the entity
 "type": "geo:json" contains the ":" character I obtain:

{"error":"InternalError","description":"Database Error (collection: orion-carouge.entities - insert(): { _id: { id: "10_Place_Nations"....

```
curl -X POST \
 http://<entityID>:port/v2/entities \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'fiware-service:carouge' \
 -H 'Fiware-ServicePath:/Traffic' \
 -d '{ "type": {
    "value": "Traffic"
 },
 "dateObserved": {
   "value": "2019-05-22T21:26:00"
 },
 "id": "10_Place_Nations",
 "location": {
   "value": {
     "coordinates": [
       [
         6.130983321064038,
         46.21602766413273
       ]
     ],
     "type" : "Point"
   },
   "type": "geo:json"
 },

}'\
```

Apparently this is not a problem in the MongoDB of Orion. I am able to insert the  "type": "geo:json" in the MongoDB. Probably some validation before making the post call, cause the problem.  Any contribution will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your request has two errors.

First, you cannot use a JSON object as entity type. Entity types must be strings. Thus you have to use:

```
"type": "Traffic"
```

Second, the GeoJSON object you are using for `location` value is incorrect. Point uses a single coordinate in `coordinates`, not a list.

In sum, the following request will work:

```
curl -X POST \
 http://localhost:1026/v2/entities \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -H 'fiware-service:carouge' \
 -H 'Fiware-ServicePath:/Traffic' \
 -d '{ "type": "Traffic",
 "dateObserved": {
   "value": "2019-05-22T21:26:00"
 },                              
 "id": "10_Place_Nations",       
 "location": {
   "value": {
     "coordinates": [       
         6.130983321064038,
         46.21602766413273     
     ],                  
     "type" : "Point"
   },                
   "type": "geo:json"
 }                                      
}'
```

Comment: Hi, I very appreciated your suggestion. I think is a good idea to pass in GeoJSON single coordinates.

Comment: You can also use the `geo:point` type. Something like this (I'm writing based in my memory :): `"location": { "value": "46.21602766413273, 6.130983321064038", "type": "geo:point" }`.  Attribute JSON is simpler.